# Time complexity $O(m+n)$ Vs $O(n)$

Tags: time-complexity, arrays, big-o-notation, iteration, linear-complexity

Consider this algorithm iterating over $2$ arrays $(A$ and $B)$

size of $ A = n$

size of $ B = m$

Please note that $m \leq n$

The algorithm is as follows

```
for every value in A:
    // code

for every value in B:
    // code
```

The time complexity of this algorithm is $O(n+m)$
But given that $m$ is strictly lesser than or equal to $n$, can this be considered as $O(n)$?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123432/discussion-on-question-by-shylajhaa-time-complexity-omn-vs-on).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes:

$n+m \le n+n=2n$ which is $O(n)$, and thus $O(n+m)=O(n)$

---

For clarity, this is true **only** under the assumption that $m\le n$. Without this assumption, $O(n)$ and $O(n+m)$ are two different things - so it would be important to write $O(n+m)$ instead of $O(n)$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123433/discussion-on-answer-by-nir-shahar-time-complexity-omn-vs-on).

Answer (score 11):

Yes, since $n + m \leq 2n$ the algorithm is $O(n)$. However, you may wish to write $O(m + n)$ because it clearly shows which variables the algorithm depends on, and what each variable does to the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

(expanding on my comment)

#### Technically No

You need to be very careful here, as there is a difference between *algorithmic* time complexity and *runtime*.  In the case you have described, the runtime may be O(n) but the algorithm itself is O(n+m).

This is because, without your *external* constraints, the algorithm's time complexity cannot be determined without knowing both `m` and `n`.

If you wanted to make the algorithm itself O(n), you would need to explicitly encode your external constraint that `m<n` within the algorithm itself.  Adding a check that aborts if  `m>n` would work.

#### Unless...

The above does not hold if `m < n` *by definition* (ie it arises from a fundamental property of your data structures).

Say, for example, `A` is an array and `B` is an array composed of only the elements at the even indices of `A`.  Then `m` is indeed `< n` by definition, and no check is required.

In cases like these the answer is yes, the algorithm is O(n).  In fact, it would be 'incorrect' (assuming you are going for a tight upper bound) to say it is O(n+m) since the asymptotic performance depends entirely on `n`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123434/discussion-on-answer-by-cole-time-complexity-omn-vs-on).