# Time complexity of repeating a procedure $k$ times

Tags: time-complexity

Suppose I want to deploy the algorithm for finding connected components in a graph $k$ many times. Now the time complexity for finding connected components in an undirected graph is $O(v+e)$. Then what will be the time complexity, $O(k(v+e))$ or $O(ke)$?

Similarly, I have deployed a method $k$ times which requires $O(n^2+n^2)$. What will be its complexity, $O(kn^2)$ or $O(k(n^2+n^2))$?

Comment: What do you think?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: This question has answers here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/139307/time-complexity-omn-vs-on

Comment: Suppose that jumping once takes 1 second. How many times does it take to jump 10 times?

Comment: In addition, $O(n^2 + n^2)$ is identical to $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that an algorithm gathers information when it's running and doesn't throw it away. If gathering that information takes O(n^2) but solving the problem with the help of the information gathered only takes O(n), then solving the same problem k times could run in O(n^2 + kn). All depends on your algorithm.